# Build configuration failed using kotlin plugin jpa

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I got an error trying to use kotlin plugin jpa and my project doesn't compile locally since my  Intellij returns the following error:

"Build configuration failed, using previous dependencies"

follow below my build.gradle file

```
    import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.1.5.RELEASE"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version "1.3.31"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.2.71"
}

group = "br.com"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    runtime("org.postgresql:postgresql")

}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mismatch in your versions: the JPA plugin (`org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa`) is set to version `1.3.31` but the Kotlin (`kotlin("jvm")`) and Kotlin Spring (`kotlin("plugin.spring")`) plugins are set to version `1.2.71`. I suggest you move everything to `1.3.31` by changing these two lines as follows:

```
kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.31"
kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.3.31"
```